# Is (λx.FV(A)) and (λx.FV(B)) β-equivalent?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Does free variables have some meaning in lambda calculus? If I follow this β-reduction

```
(λx.λz.y x) y
    -> (λz.y x){x/y}        (variable FV(y) captured)
    -> ((λz.y x){a/y}){x/y} (rename FV(y) -> FV(a)){
    -> (λz.a x){x/y}
    -> (λz.a y)
```

Here we have FV(y) captured during the β-reduction, so I rename it to FV(a) and continue the reduction. Is this result even valid?

I would rename the y argument instead

```
(λx.λz.y x) y
    -> (λz.y x){x/y}        (variable FV(y) captured)
    -> (λz.y x)({x/y}{y/a}) (rename argument FV(y) -> FV(a)
    -> (λz.y x){x/a}
    -> (λz.y a)
```

If I use De Bruijin index notation for both outputs I would get:

```
(λz.a y) -> (λ.1 2)
(λz.y a) -> (λ.1 2)
```

so they seem β-equivalent for me.

This means that FV has no meaning at all, `FV(a) β= FV(b) β= FV(c) ...`  is my understanding right?

I'm asking because when applying lambda calculus I would like to have some global variables that are not bound by the expression but are bound by the context, things like `*`, `+`, `sqrt`, etc, in this case I cant just replace free variables because they may have a meaning, what would I do so?

---

Thanks @lemontree for your answer, I'm implementing a lambda calcualtor so I need to take care of every single step. I write things in the math notation `(λx.x) y` and then translate to the expected code `Appl(Lamb('x', 'x'), 'y')`, `M[x/y]` `m.replace('x', 'y')`, so having a notation for every step help me a lot :).

I search but can't find any special notation for ɑ-conversion so I came up with `M[BV(x)/y]` to denote that x is not free in `M` and to make it distinct from `M[x/y]`. And a special function `NX` that returns the next available variables. Here is how I reduced your example (thank you!)

```
    (λx.λy.y x) y
        -> (λy.y x)[y/x]
        -> (λy.y[y/x] x[y/x])               CAPTURE ERROR on y (backtrack)
        -> (λy.y x)[BV(y)/NX(x, y)][y/x]    NX(FV ∪ BV) returns the next available variable
        -> (λy.y x)[BV(y)/z][y/x]
        -> (λz.z x)[y/x]
        -> (λz.z[y/x] x[y/x])
        -> (λz.z y)
```

The bits that I missed

- A definition of available variables `not (FV ∪ BV)`. I need this to implement ɑ-conversion
- A formal notation for ɑ-conversion

Is there anything like this in the literature? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free variables have a "meaning" in the sense that two free variables (as opposed to two bound variables) are not $\alpha$-equivalent -- and that's precisely why your first reduction is *not* correct: We are not allowed to do "free renaming", only bound renaming!

Capture avoiding substitution is defined as

> If $x \neq y$ and $y \in FV(N)$ and $x \in FV(P)$, then, where $z \not \in FV(N) \cup FV(P)$:
> $(\lambda y.P)[N/x] = \lambda z.(P[z/y][N/x])$

Capture avoiding substitution happens only when a variable occurring free in $N$ is bound by lambda abstraction in the term to substitute ($y \in FV(N)$) and there are actual occurrences of $x$ in $P$ to substitute ($x \neq y$ and $x \in FV(P)$). In that case, we rename the *bound* variable in *the term that undergoes* substitution (the function body), i.e. $(\lambda y.P) \rightsquigarrow \lambda z. (P[z/y])$, then perform the actual substitution of $N$ for $x$ in $P'$. **We do not rename free variables, and we do not perform renaming in the argument**.

In your example, beta-reducing $(λx.λz.y x) y$ means to replace every free occurrence of $x$ in $\lambda z. yx$ by $y$ provided that $y$ is free to substitute. **y will not be captured by anything**: As you observe, $y$ is free in $\lambda z.yx$, and that's precisely why there is no capturing and thus no capture avoiding to perform, and the substitution can be done directly. Thus the correct reduction is

> $\newcommand{\bred}{\triangleright_\beta}
> \phantom{\triangleright_\beta} (\lambda x. \lambda z. yx)y\\
> \bred (\lambda z.yx)[y/x]\\
> = \lambda z. (yx[y/x])\\
> = \lambda z. (y[y/x])(x[y/x])\\
> = \lambda z. yy$

De Bruijn indexing on this term is vacuous, because there are no pairs of binding and bound variables ($\lambda z$ does not bind any occurrences of $z$, and the two occurrences of $y$ are not bound by any abstraction $\lambda y$).

---

A case where capture avoiding substitution would be needed is if the argument $y$ were bound in the function body, e.g. if instead of the vacuous abstraction $\lambda z$ there were $\lambda y$:

> $(\lambda x. \lambda y. yx)y\\
> \bred (\lambda y.yx)[y/x]\\
> = \lambda z. (yx[z/y][y/x]) \quad \text{(avoiding catpure of $y$)}\\
> = \lambda z. (zx[y/x])\\
> = \lambda z. zy$

---

Re. notation and implementation:

It depends a bit on how you define it, but the way I used it above (which is the approach chosen in e.g. Hindley & Seldin (see below):
When bound renaming has to happen to avoid variable capture, then this is part of the definition of substitution, i.e. the result of $(\lambda y.P)[N/x]$ with $y$ free in $N$ syntactically identical ("$=$", rather than just $\alpha$-equivalent) to $\lambda z.P[z/y][N/x]$.
To express $\alpha$-equivalence in the sense that a pair of terms only differs in their bound variable names, you can write $\equiv_\alpha$.
Alternatively, one could define beta reduction such that substitution can only be performed if no variable conflict occurs, and if it does, one has to prepend a step of $\alpha$-renaming before $\beta$-reducing.

"not $FV(A) \cup FV(B)$" is just the set-theoretic complement relative to the set of all variables, $VAR - (FV(A) \cup FV(B))$. To implement a choice of "the first variable not in $FV(A) \cup FV(B)$" you need to presuppose an ordering of variables such as $x < y < z < x_1 < ... x_n$ and then do something like $min\{x: x \in VAR \land x \not \in FV(A) \land x \not \in FV(B)\}$. The set of free and bound variables is defined by straightforward recursion on the structure of the lambda term.

Furthermore, for a precise notation in the implementation one may want to distinguish between an atomic beta reduction/variable renaming step vs. reducibility/equivalence through a chain of reductions/renamings, as well as $\beta$-reducibility monotonously downwards from $A$ to $B$ as opposed to $\beta$-equivalence by finding a common term both reduce to.

For variables you should use $x, y, z, u, v, w, x_1, x_2, \ldots$; wheras $a, b, c, \ldots$ are more typically understood as constants.
Constants is also what objects and functions interpreted "by context" such as $*, +, sqrt$ would naturally be treated as; their meaning is "fixed from the outside" and you can combine lambda reduction with custom inference steps like $(\lambda x.+xx)(2) \bred +22 =_\mathbb{N} 4$.

You can find the notation I used and all the definitions necessary for rigorously implementing substitution etc. in (amongst others)

J. R. Hindley & J.P. Seldin (2008), *Lambda calculus and combinators: an introduction*.

Another classic is

H. Barendregt (1992), *Lambda calculi with types*.

Comment: So my problem was understanding the capture, can you, please, give me an example of a β-reduction where substitution is needed?

Comment: @geckos I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help @lemontree it is very helpful :)

Comment: As a last question, is there any notation for ɑ-conversion? Something like (λx.x)[z/x] = (λz.z), I know that M[z/x] usually means _replace all free x by z_ but in this case x is not free, is there any special notation for that?

Comment: I updated the question with more information on the alpha notation doubts I hope I'm not bothering :)

Comment: @geckos See my edit.